# How do I make Asp.net recognize Ext JS form submittion as an Ajax request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, extjs, form-submit

It seems like by default, Asp.net does not recognize Ext JS `getForm().submit()` calls as an ajax request.  This is causing an issue for me because I am trying to return a `JsonResult` instead of a view if the request was made via Ajax.

However, when the following gets called

```
        this.getForm().submit({
            url: url,
            waitMsg: 'Saving Request Details',
            scope: this,
            success: function (form, o) {
                ...
            },

            failure: function (form, o) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

inside of my Asp.net MVC action that gets called, `HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()` is returning false.

How can I make it so Asp.Net correctly recognizes the request as an ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuo can alway add hidden parameter in you form what will determ that this request is via AJAX

Comment: That's a good idea.  Going to mark this as the answer only because I cannot seem to find a way to add headers to Ext JS form submissions, as the submit method seems to ignore all added headers.

Answer (score 2):

That extension looks for a value in the header or in the request collection of key "X-Requested-With" with a matching value of "XMLHttpRequest".  You would have to set the value when you make the request because it seems like extJS isn't.

Try including an X-Requested-With entry within the form results and see if that remedies it.

HTH.

Comment: Hrm that makes sense.  Do you have any idea how to edit a request header entry in Ext JS by any chance?